# How do you use (list-at-point) in elisp?

Tags: elisp

I sometimes use (number-at-point), (string-at-point), (sexp-at-point) and I had a need for:

(list-at-point)

I want to be able to grab some text like:

a b c d

and use list-at-point to grab it as an elisp list, and then do some processing on it.

But I can't seem to get list-at-point to return anything but nil.

I'm using Emacs on windows, v22.3.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears you've found a bug,  None of the functions that depend on `form-at-point` seem to work for me, which the ones that depend on `thing-at-point` do.  Have a look at the file `thngatpt.el` in the elisp sources.

The function has sufficient hair that I can't debug it at this hour, but it's clearly not doing what it advertises.   Googling reveals other complaints.

You might see if replacing it with [`thingatpt+.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/thingatpt+.el) is better.

Comment: yeah, I looked at the code a little bit, but there's enough funcall magic going on it'll require some thought.

Comment: Yeah it is a bug. I reported it and it's been fixed.

Answer (score 1):

with lisp, you may use the parentize commands delivered at

http://launchpad.net/s-x-emacs-werkstatt/

see downloads

;;;
ar-parentized-atpt is an interactive Lisp function in
`thing-at-point-utils.el'.

It is bound to s-).

(ar-parentized-atpt &optional ARG NO-DELIMITERS)

Returns parentized at point if any, nil otherwise. Optional NO-DELIMITERS trims THING, i.e. returns delimited objects like `brackteted',`braced' etc. without delimiters.